# C# Bool operand usage

Tags: boolean, boolean-operations

I want to have the following results

```
A B =
T T T
F T F
T F F
F F F
```

I am using this clause to achieve it

```
A || B
```

but it does not provide correct results.

Am I using a wrong operand?

Comment: use and operator A && B

Comment: @HimBromBeere Becuase `||` is a logic operator in C#?

Comment: @InBetween That applies for many languages.

Comment: @HimBromBeere thats irrelevant, the OP doesn't necessarily have to know *anything*, and probably doesn't, about other languages. He's coding in C# and asking about C#.

Comment: @InBetween However the question doesn't have anything C# specific, it's how a boolean table and operations work. Once they know the answer, they can locate the correct operator they need for the language themself

Comment: @InBetween That is true. But for a question for C# I´d expect some code showing the OPs problem. Currently this is just an algebratic question, not related to programming at all.

Comment: The question has `A||B` in C#. I think it does not matter that it would also be valid in other languages. I think it is a good idea by OP to define the language of code used in the question even if it is short code which would be valid in other languages, too. Maybe even more then as OP cannot be excpected to know if the answer would have been different in another language.

Comment: @Draken thats a fine line you are drawing there. *Many* questions can be considered language agnostic under that light. Anyhow, not really worth discussing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allthough all other answers are correct, I'd like to point out that the operator you are asking for is neither `||` nor `&&`. The operator that actually does exactly what you are asking for is `&` (and the equivalent that you are mistakenly using would be `|`).

And, what is the difference? `||` and `&&` are short circuiting operators. What does that mean? It means that whatever is on the right side of the operator is *only evaluated* if the left hand side is `true`. This does not happen with the non short circuit versions of the operators (the truly bolean logical *and* and *or* operators):

```
public bool True()
{
    Console.WriteLine("True called.");
    return true;
}

public bool False()
{
    Console.WriteLine("False called.");
    return false;
}

var b1 = False() && True(); //b1 will be false and "False called." will be 
                            //printed on the console. 

var b2 = False() & True();  //b2 will be false and "False called. True called." 
                            //will be printed on the console.
```

Answer (score 3):

You want an `and`, but you used an `or`.

Comment: apparently it is not very clear to the OP how exactly these operators work. A little clarification on this would really enhance the answer

Answer (score 3):

> Am I using a wrong operand?

Yes you are.

You need the **AND** `&&` operator which will be true only if all of the conditions are **true**.

You are using the **OR** `||` operator which will give you true even if one of the conditions are **true**.

Use the **AND** `&&` operator instead of **OR** `||`

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&` (which means 'and')

`||` means 'or'

Comment: apparently it is not very clear to the OP how exactly these operators work. A little clarification on this would really enhance the answer